# Restlet: Pass Java interface as @Put parameter

Tags: java, rest, interface, restlet, restlet-2.0

I'd like to pass a java interface to a @Put call:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
...
}

public class MyClass implements IMyInterface, Serializable {
...
}

public class Service extends ServerResource {

    @Put
    public void f(IMyInterface a) {
        ...
    }

}
```

When I call f() through a ClientResource, I get the error message "Unsupported Media Type (415)" which I presume is because IMyInterface is not serializable.

Is it possible to pass a MyClass object as IMyInterface?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make JSON/XML serializer to work with interfces with the help of @XmlSeeAlso and @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotations.

See:

- [Jersey REST/ JAXB error , mapping an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931960/jersey-rest-jaxb-error-mapping-an-interface) and
- http://www.attivio.com/blog/56-java-development/636-configuring-java-interfaces-to-work-with-jaxb-and-web-services.html

for an example. It would not hurt to add

```
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Consumes("application/json")
@PUT
public void f(IMyInterface a) {
    ...
}
```